# Firebase Cloud Functions Pricing Model

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've got a very simple question about the pricing model of Cloud Functions. I have read the documentation and visited other relevant sites, but one question remains unanswered. For me, the sentence "The first 2,000,000 function invocations are free" is ambiguous as there are two interpretations for this:

1. The first 2,000,000 invocations for a **single** function are free
2. The first 2,000,000 invocations for the **entire set** of functions are free

Common sense tells me that the second interpretation is correct, but can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience the second one is correct it represent the (function invocation) not a single specific function (invocation)